# Webflux postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-webflux

How should I implement postgresql in Webflux?
I would like to do it with `ReactiveCrudRepository`, but JPA isn't reactive... I want to store users and SSH public and private keys. I've read that MongoDB transactions aren't as reliable as postgresql(Correct me if I am wrong). Thats why I want to use postgresql.

But what is the best way to use Postgresql in webflux? I would like to use JPA repositories(or other) and not write full queries, but still be able to program reactively.

Comment: Check [my sample for Spring Data R2dbc](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-data-r2dbc),  R2dbc officially supports H2 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Still no official driver for Pg.
I didn't really use it but here is a try at this github [link](https://github.com/alaisi/postgres-async-driver).

Take a look at [Redis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:reactive:connectors) as an alternative to mongodb: It can be both in memory db and ordinary datasource.

Hope was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think Redis is the right database for my application... Also the async postgres library only works with full queries and not with a query builder...

Answer (score 1):

There is no "official" reactive JDBC driver yet (as of March 2019). However, there are many 3rd party reactive drivers for postgres. I used David Moten's rxjava2-jdbc library and postgres jdbc driver

I wrote a tutorial/example using webflux, kotlin and postgres (rxjava2-jdbc) here:
https://medium.com/@dvliman/building-a-reactive-web-service-with-spring-webflux-kotlin-and-postgresql-71c4e0c2f870

and the source code here: https://github.com/dvliman/spring-webflux-kotlin-postgresql/

but I wasn't using JPA - I would manually marshall data, write queries/functions to operate on the data.